# How do you delete the default database/schema in hsqldb

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I've created an in memory hsqldb and am using the default database/schema. Now I want to drop and recreate the database programatically.

How do I do that?

Comment: did you take a look at http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101EF ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE

This will purge the public schema. If you create other schemas, use the same command with the schema name instead of PUBLIC.

Comment: BTW, adding "CASCADE" also helped me to solve the issue "dependent privilege descriptors still exist in statement" when I tried to run DROP SCHEMA once again on the same schema.